# Invalid read of size 1 when using valgrind

Tags: c, linked-list, asprintf

I am getting this output when using valgrind:

```
==19923== Invalid read of size 1
==19923==    at 0x52CCCC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==19923==    by 0x52F4772: vasprintf (vasprintf.c:59)
==19923==    by 0x52D3A56: asprintf (asprintf.c:35)
==19923==    by 0x400D77: addToList (pa1.c:124)
==19923==    by 0x4010AF: md5Hash (pa1.c:220)
==19923==    by 0x401138: newFile (pa1.c:244)
==19923==    by 0x401260: searchDirects (pa1.c:280)
==19923==    by 0x401451: main (pa1.c:339)
==19923==  Address 0x585b720 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 27 free'd
==19923==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19923==    by 0x401144: newFile (pa1.c:246)
==19923==    by 0x401260: searchDirects (pa1.c:280)
==19923==    by 0x401382: directoryCheck (pa1.c:312)
==19923==    by 0x4012CD: searchDirects (pa1.c:290)
==19923==    by 0x401451: main (pa1.c:339)
==19923==  Block was alloc'd at
==19923==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19923==    by 0x52F47D7: vasprintf (vasprintf.c:73)
==19923==    by 0x52D3A56: asprintf (asprintf.c:35)
==19923==    by 0x40112C: newFile (pa1.c:239)
==19923==    by 0x401260: searchDirects (pa1.c:280)
==19923==    by 0x401382: directoryCheck (pa1.c:312)
==19923==    by 0x4012CD: searchDirects (pa1.c:290)
==19923==    by 0x401451: main (pa1.c:339)
```

Here is where I have narrowed it down to being the problem in my code:

```
else
{    
    currentList = headList;
    printf("This is where I will put the code to create the Linked list!\n");
    if(currentList != 0)
    {
        while(currentList->nextList != 0)
        {
            if(currentList->key = key)
            {
                asprintf(&buff, "%s %s", currentList->value, dirValue); // PROBLEM IS HERE
                printf("Here is the new string that holds the directory paths: %s\n", buff);
                currentList->value = buff;
                free(buff);
                printf("Here is the new string that holds the directory paths: %s\n", currentList->value);
                return;
            }
            currentList = currentList->nextList;
        }

        currentList->nextList = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
        printf("Adding a new node\n");
        //Reached the end of the Linked list and didn't find the
        //same key so create a new node.
        currentList = currentList->nextList;
        currentList->key = key;
        currentList->nextList = NULL;
        currentList->value = dirValue;
    }
}
```

I have many errors, and providing the entire valgrind output would be overkill I feel. All of the errors I am getting come back to where I am using asprintf() `("addToList (pa1.c:124)" line in the report)`. Above the code I initialize `char *buff = NULL;`, and `currentList->value` holds a string that I am wanting to append onto using asprintf. Any guesses to why I am getting the numerous Invalid read size 1 errors would be greatly appreciated. Also, the string is appended as expected when I do print out the result from asprintf() Thanks.

Comment: Not sure whether it causes the exact error but `if(currentList->key = key)` needs to be `if(currentList->key == key)`

Comment: The valgrind error says you're trying to use freed memory.

Comment: `currentList->value = buff; free(buff);` ? Deallocating something you are linked to seems to be a serious logic error at least.

Comment: `currentList->value = buff; free(buff);` makes no sense. Why assign a pointer you're about to free?

Comment: @kaylum - Yep, you are absolutely correct. Thanks, for spotting that!

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunes - Haha, you and melpomene both made me realize the mistake I was doing. Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene - Please see my above comment. However, you are correct and I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invalid read is at the start of an already freed block of memory; you are trying to use memory after you've freed it.

```
currentList->value = buff;
free(buff);
printf("Here is the new string that holds the directory paths: %s\n", currentList->value);
return;
```

You use `currentList->value = buff;` in the `printf()`, but you've just freed `buff`.  This spells an impending disaster.  If `currentList->value` is going to be used in calling functions after the `return`, you've got major problems.

You can fix the one warning by moving the `printf()` before the `free()`, but the code looks like you're going to have major issues.  It might be better to delete the `free(buff);` — though you'd have to work out where the data is actually freed instead.

Comment: Although both the users in the above comments pointed out my flaw, I am marking your answer correct for clarity. I removed the free because I actually need the new string. Silly mistake, but another explanation of what I was doing made it quite clear what my issue was (the calling of free'd memory as you mentioned above). Thanks!